# <g:each> Specify controller and action?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm attempting to call a method from a controller in my grails project that I can iterate over and display items in a list.

```
//Controller code
Class TicketController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def ticketsByDate = {
    return [tickets : Ticket.list(sort: 'dateCreated')]
}
...

GSP code

<div class="box-content">
        <ul class="tickets">
            <g:each var="ticket" in="${ticketsByDate}" controller="ticket">
                <li>${ticket.id}</li>
            </g:each>
```

I might be looking at this from the wrong perspective, but what I want to be able to do is to make multiple calls like this from a page that aggregates data from several different sources.  These sources would most likely be controller methods that made calls to services.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs of the each tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html). It is used to iterates over an collection.
You have to pass this collection from your controller to the view.

For your example - put the following snippet into your `ticketsByDate` view:

```
<g:each var="ticket" in="${tickets}">
    <li>${ticket.id}</li>
</g:each>
```

If you want to iterate over different objects of data sources you have to aggregate the data within your controller and pass them to view:

```
def ticketsByDate = {
    return [tickets : Ticket.list(sort: 'dateCreated'), 
            moreTickets : AnotherThicket.list(), 
            users: User.list(),                 
            ...]
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Include everything I'll need in the return map.  I was looking at it incorrectly- Is it safe to say that you can't call a controller outside of the one serving the view?  Thanks for helping a grails newby!

Comment: If you would like to use the default grails tags, you have to put everything in the return map. Alternatively you could use the 'AJAX-way' by fetching the data after page rendering ...